# Which is more correct stop loss for opening buy position in mt4?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

so far, I did use this formula without question.

`stoploss = NormalizeDouble(Ask - StopLossInPoint * Point, Digits);`

But today's sudden price spike made me think about it again.
I guessed Ask price(XAUUSD, 2023.11.14 GMT+2 15:30) was unreasonably big at that moment.
Because my log message says that the stoploss(300point based) computed with above formula was even bigger than the chart-displayed price level(I hope it's Bid price what I see in chart), whereas it should be smaller than it.

```
Long Order Failed with error #130, which means invalid stop loss.
```

So I think the spread was approached 300 point, and failed to open position.

- Can I use Bid for computing stop loss of buy position like this?

  `stoploss = NormalizeDouble(Bid - StopLossInPoint * Point, Digits);`
- What could using Bid make unexpected result?

some sites requires to use **Bid**.
https://www.earnforex.com/guides/ordersend-error-130/
I inspected open sources in github, and many of them is based on **Ask**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho for BUY orders You should use

`double sl = NormalizeDouble(symbolInfo.Bid() - StopLevel * point, (int)digits);`

and for SELL orders You should use

`double sl = NormalizeDouble(symbolInfo.Ask() + StopLevel * point, (int)digits);`

-it is from my mql5 but it is almost the same in older

and the same thing is suggested on this website that You posted link to.

Comment: Thanks @Dorian. I'll upvote you when I have 15 reputation.

Comment: also remember that tp is oposite so for buy - tp should use Ask and Bid for sell =]